# Unordered pairs in Homotopy Type Theory

Tags: homotopy-type-theory

It's conceptually simple to state what an "unordered pair" is supposed to be in set theory. Yet, in homotopy type theory I have trouble formalizing this. A first naive try in agda syntax:

```
data UPair (A : Type ℓ) : Type ℓ where
  mkpair : (x y : A) → UPair A
  uswap : ∀ a b → mkpair a b ≡ mkpair b a
```

This fails, since there are actually two different paths between e.g. `mkpair 1 2` and `mkpair 2 1`, that is we have `uswap 1 2` and `sym (uswap 2 1)`. Again, these can be forced equal by a one-higher path constructor, but one would have to continue for ever.

Obviously, if `A` is an `n`-truncated type, we can stop at some point. Generally truncating at some level fails because it might forget some non-trivial paths in `A`. Take for example the set-truncation of the above type and `A = S¹`, the circle, then the path `i. mkpair (loop i) base` is lost and identified with `refl (mkpair base base)`.

Can we generally write down the type of unordered pairs of a parameter `A : Type ℓ`? Can the resulting type live inside the universe `ℓ`?

---

Clarification:

Let `A· = (A , a)` be a pointed type. Define `UPA· = (UPair A, mkpair a a)` as a pointed type. I would then expect `Ωₜ UPA· ≡ UPair (Ωₜ A·)`. These correspond to singleton sets.

Let `A∙ = (A, a, b)` be a bipointed type with `a ≢ b`. Then I expect that the map `(a ≡ a) × (b ≡ b) → mkpair a b ≡ mkpair b a` given by `(pa , pb) → (λ i → mkpair (pa i) (pb i)) ∙ uswap a b` is an equivalence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of unordered pairs in a type $A$ is defined to be $$\sum_{(X:\mathcal{U})}\sum_{(H:\|X\simeq \mathsf{bool}\|)}A^X.$$ In other words, an undordered pair in $A$ is simply a map $X\to A$ from a type $X$ that merely has two elements.

Note that in general, this is not a set, because the type of 2-element types is not a set but a 1-type. The way to think about this is that unordered pairs have some symmetries (swapping the order of the elements in the unordered pairs) that should be taken into account in homotopy type theory.

Note that the type of unordered pairs can also be used to define the type of fully coherent commutative binary operations on a type $A$. This type is simply $$\Big(\sum_{(X:\mathcal{U})}\sum_{(H:\|X\simeq\mathsf{bool}\|)}A^X\Big)\to A.$$
In other words, a fully coherent commutative binary operation on $A$ is an operation on the unordered pairs of $A$.

Comment: Another application of the same idea is the type of non-planar binary trees: it is the inductive type $T$ equipped with a base point $r:T$ and an operation $\mathsf{unordered{-}pairs}(T)\to T$

Comment: At first sight, this seems like a straightforward definition with the correct paths, at least I think I can see how to define `mkpair` and a better version of `uswap` that doesn't have the problems I had. Very insightful. This generalizes to n-tuples (and other container types) where equivalence is permutations?!

Comment: It generalizes indeed. The type of unordered lists of elements in $A$ is defined to be $S(A):=\sum_{X:\mathbb{F}}A^X$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the type of all merely finite types. The type $S(A)$ should be the free symmetric monoid on $A$, although to state that, you'd have to solve an infinite coherence problem.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can still pretty easily define some of the low-dimensional structure on $S(A)$, that you'd expect from the free symmetric monoid.

Answer (score 1):

The *set* of unordered pairs of `A` can be defined using a higher-inductive type with set-truncation, just as you suggested, somewhat like this (I am writing this off the top of my head without verifying it in Agda, but you'll get the point):

```
data UPair (A : Type ℓ) : Type ℓ where
  mkpair : (x y : A) → UPair A
  uswap : ∀ a b → mkpair a b ≡ mkpair b a
  trunc : ∀ (u v : UPair A) (p q : u ≡ v) → p ≡ q
```

It is obvious that `UPair A` is a set (is a $0$-type) because `trunc` directly witnessess this fact. You do not have to add any higher-path constructors.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking. This is somewhat unsatisfactory since `UPair A ≡ UPair ∥ A ∥₀` for any A, so it is the set of unordered *sets* (though perfectly good for that).

Comment: If `A` is not a set, then what do you expect `UPair A` to be, mathematically speaking? For instance, what is `UPair S¹`?

Comment: Since the loop space `Ω S¹` is `Int`, I would expect `Ω (UPair S¹)` to be `UPair Int`.

Comment: `UPair S¹` should be like the torus `S¹ x S¹` but you can swap the two directions "up" and "around".

Comment: Naive informal descriptions do not reveal what higher-path structure you might be thinking of. What does this "swap" mean, are you talking about a homotopy pushout of some sort, or what? For instance, would you expect `UPair A` to have the same truncation level as `A`?

Comment: I have given clarification in the question, that I hope clears up a bit of confusion. I haven't convinced myself that the type I search for is completely determined up to equivalence, except for the examples already talked about (Sets and types with a single point).

Comment: I refer you to @Egbert's answer who certainly knows more about this than I do.